# Set mouse wheel scrolling direction in Mac OS X and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, mouse-wheel

Mouse wheels behave just the opposite in Windows and Mac OS X. When playing with a web page, the action that scrolls up in MS Windows actually scrolls down in Mac OS X.

Is setting in either OS possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *System Preferences » Mouse* on your Mac and remove the first checkbox:

[image]

This affects mouse and trackpad alike, if have have both. It's something you were shown when you logged in after Lion installation for the first time.

[image]

---

See [this How-To-Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/57542/how-to-get-the-worst-os-x-lion-feature-in-windows-reverse-scrolling/) to get reverse scrolling in Windows using AutoHotkey.

Comment: what about in MS Windows?

Comment: @onemach See that last paragraph with the link to the How-To Geek site. It's not supported by the OS, you need additional software, e.g. AutoHotkey, for it.